# What is the best way to upload a file from android app if server is apollo graphql server

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

I should upload a file to server from Android app using Apollo framework. The problem is that I couldn't find any library and any example for that. Is there any solution that you can provide? How to upload a file from mobile using Apollo framework? Any idea?

Comment: what client you use to consume graphql queries and mutations?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apollo client for android to consume graphql queries and mutations you have to add **customTypeMapping** in your build.gradle file

```
apollo {
  customTypeMapping = [
    "Upload" : "com.apollographql.apollo.api.FileUpload"
  ]
}
```

The Upload is a scalar recognized by graphql for uploading files to a server.

Here is how to upload a file with a apollo client for android [link](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#support-file-upload)

Comment: Also `customTypeMapping.set(mapOf("Upload" to "com.apollographql.apollo.api.FileUpload"))`